# oauth2 - Authorization Flow

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization, single-sign-on

I've a question about oauth2 and its suitability in this case. I've looked at the authorization flow, but that always seems to start the process from the 3rd party web app, not from the portal (auth server)...

My terminology...

1) We have Enterprise Portal system (e.g. SharePoint etc), let's call it portal.com
2) We have a 3rd party hosted web app, let's call it webapp.com

A user, already logged in (authenticated) in portal.com clicks a link on one of the portal pages that opens up webapp.com (my 3rd party, cross domain web app). I want to authorize the user to use webapp.com without the need for supplying any extra login credentials.

Questions:

a) is oauth2 the most common 'standards' based way to do this? Or have I misunderstood something.
b) If it is, what is the authorization flow? (I only seem to find auth flows that start from the user visiting webapp.com FIRST, then directing to portal.com to login, then redirecting back. But in my user story, the user visits portal.com first and is already logged in when they are linked to webapp.com).

Apologies if my terminology is poor - I am new to this area.

Cheers,
Ollie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically OAuth 2.0 has been created as Authorization protocol, but it is easily usable for Authentication (Identity Provider) as well and suits your situation rather well. You may however investigate OpenID Connect (OIDC) - which is an extension of the OAuth 2.0 exactly in the area of Authentication / Identity Provider.

If you have got a User Session on your Portal, then it is absolutely fine if you simply redirect to your WebApp and then the WebApp (which has no session yet) requests User Identity from the Portal by the means of OAuth 2.0 / OIDC. User would get extra 2 redirects without noticing anything but this way the login would also work fine if user bookmarks your WebApp and accesses it without first entering portal.com.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you are looking for a solution of **single sign-on**. If so, OAuth 2.0 ([RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)) cannot help you. OAuth 2.0 is a specification for **authorization**, not for **authentication**. It explicitly states as follows.

> *The way in which the authorization server **authenticates** the resource owner (e.g., username and password login, session cookies) is **beyond the scope of this specification**.*

**Authentication** deals with information about *"**who** one is"*. On the other hand,
**authorization** deals with information about *"**who** grants **what permissions** to **whom**"*. So, OAuth 2.0 is not the keyword for your case.

Comment: Ok... I actually control the webapp (webapp.com). How do I allow an authenticated user of portal.com enter my site (without needing to register again), in a standards based manner?

Comment: and by that, I mean I want to offer capability for multiple different portals to access my webapp.com without having to sign in again.

Comment: If you can control both portal.com and webapp.com, isn't it enough to allow both the servers to access your database which manages authentication data (= session IDs)? For example, if the server hosting the database provides Web APIs to manage (create/verify/renew/etc) session IDs and both portal.com and webapp.com can access the APIs, the frontend servers can share session IDs. It is when you cannot control webapp.com that you have to google 'Single sign-on' for standard-based solutions.

Comment: Sorry, should have made this clear - We only control the webapp.com